# Condição de uma consulta com uma subconsulta

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Eu preciso atualizar os 110 últimos registros da tabela `relevo`, porém o meu problema está na subconsulta presente no `WHERE`.

Estou fazendo desta maneira:

```
UPDATE relevo
SET id_projeto = 157
WHERE id_relevo = (SELECT id_relevo FROM relevo 
ORDER BY id_relevo DESC
LIMIT 110)
```

O seguinte erro está sendo retornado:

> You can't specify target table 'relevo' for update in FROM clause

Tentei também da seguinte maneira:

```
UPDATE relevo
SET id_projeto = ?
WHERE id_relevo IN (SELECT id_relevo FROM relevo 
ORDER BY id_relevo DESC
LIMIT 110)
```

O erro retornado:

> This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse negócio de atualizar os últimos registros não dá muito certo, é frágil, pode dar o resultado esperado uma vez e não em outra.

Mas se for insistir nisso faça de forma simples, não use `SELECT`:

```
UPDATE relevo
    SET id_projeto = 157
    ORDER BY id_relevo DESC
    LIMIT 110
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/Limit.sql)

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html).

Comment: Muito obrigada!